# What's this icon that looks like 3 vertical waves in the status bar of my Droid X?

Tags: motorola-droid-x, notification-icons

There's this vertical river-looking icon thing in my status bar? Nothing's claiming it in the notification window.

Crude recreation:

[image]

Comment: [Complete Android Guide](http://www.completeguides.net/01_The_Complete_Android_Guide/Chapter_04_Notifications_and_the_Notification_Bar) has nothing. I suspect it's a particular app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The third table in this page mentions "Vibrate":
https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/48504/~/droid-x---phone-status-%26-notifications

Even though the first table clearly depicts a different icon for the vibration mode, although with the same zigzag pattern.

The pattern is also the same as the icon I have for vibration mode on my SGS:

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: Yup, the update (2.3) for the Droid X made the icon even more abstract and didn't include a phone thing.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the icon for the "Silent" or "Vibrate" mode.  These icons are different depending on the skin manufacturers/carriers put on their phone, but those wavy lines usually represent vibration.